# How do I get color coded console output from SBT on OSX?

Tags: macos, scala, colors, sbt

Right now the only color in my SBT output is in the line prefixes (e.g. `[info]`, `[error]`, etc.) and stage information (e.g. `== compile ==`, etc.).

Is it possible to get color information for the filenames and line numbers of errors?

For example, in the output:

```
[error] /src/main/scala/DataLoader.scala:108: value id is not a member of Entity
```

At the very least, I would like `DataLoader` and `108` to be a different color than the default terminal color.

(Look, even SO can do it!)

Comment: Please give me a hint how you colored even [info] and [error]. I use SBT on OSX within iTerm2 and everything is white and black.

Comment: @Lars Schneider -- I use a theme in my terminal, I believe it is a slight variant of the "Grass" theme.

Answer (score 1):

Check your sbt launch script using the text editor of your choice.  The default one will have something like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

If it does, just remove the `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true` part and it should then show colour.